# camunda - how to get task name using Zeebe API

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda, zeebe

I have a process in camunda, it has a Zeebe API, as I understand it, the backend communicates with camunda through it. I need, that by userId and Instance Id, I would give the name on which task this user is currently on. "- at this stage the user is now. I looked at how Ui is formed - there is a giant xml that is very inconvenient to parse, and this is not obtained through the Zeebe API, I think there is a more normal way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6bha.jpg)

I tried to make a query like

```
        return zeebeClient
                .newCreateInstanceCommand()
                .bpmnProcessId(startSimpleParameters.processName)
                .version(version)
                .variables(variables)
                .requestTimeout(timeout)
                .send()
                .await()
```

and expect to be able to get the current task the user is on and its name from the schema.

Comment: What version of Camunda are you using? What do you get from that query? Please edit your question to clarify it in general

Comment: The problem is that in my organization, it is impossible to raise the service locally, from the infrastructure, and I cannot connect to the team because of the gatekeepers and the keclock. I cannot make a request and see what is returned locally, all services are developed using autotests and there I can write anything as a mock response. This makes development very difficult, the only way to see the response is to install the command locally and connect to it, but this is very labor intensive.

Comment: Maybe it will be better to ask in the Camunda Platform Forum

Comment: Thanks, I'll try posting there.